# Create script for wordpress site that will direct return user to different landing page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies

I appreciate everyone's help in these forums! I'm SLOWLY self-teaching my way through javascript and jquery, but at my current job I'm being asked to do something with our wordpress site that has me stumped.

I'm trying to set a cookie when first time users visit [www.website.org/](http://www.website.org/) that will steer them to [www.website.org/home](http://www.website.org/home) when they return and have cookie set.

I know obviously with private browsing and cookie clearing this isn't a perfect fix, but it'll work for us for now. Basically, I want new users to see our onboarding homepage, and return users to see slightly different content on /home.

Any help with the javascript on this would be MUCH appreciated, as my attempts have been failing miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [init hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) to redirect users.

Best wishes, Mitchell

Example:

```
add_action('init', 'check_cookie', 0, 0);
function check_cookie() {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['home'])) {
        wp_safe_redirect('/home/');
        exit;
    }
}
```